# for loop over list KeyError: 664

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to iterate this list with words as

```
CTCCTC TCCTCT CCTCTC CTCTCC TCTCCC CTCCCA TCCCAA CCCAAA CCAAAC CAAACT  
CTGGGC TGGGCC GGGCCA GGCCAA GCCAAT CCAATG CAATGC AATGCC ATGCCT TGCCTG GCCTGC  
TGCCAG GCCAGG CCAGGA CAGGAG AGGAGG GGAGGG GAGGGG AGGGGC GGGGCT GGGCTG GGCTGG GCTGGT CTGGTC 
TGGTCT GGTCTG GTCTGG TCTGGA CTGGAC TGGACA GGACAC GACACT ACACTA CACTAT  
ATTCAG TTCAGC TCAGCC CAGCCA AGCCAG GCCAGT CCAGTC CAGTCA AGTCAA GTCAAC TCAACA CAACAC AACACA 
ACACAA CACAAG ACAAGG AGGTGG GGTGGC GTGGCC TGGCCT GGCCTG GCCTGC CCTGCA CTGCAC 
TGCACT GCACTC CACTCG ACTCGA CTCGAG TCGAGG CGAGGT GAGGTT AGGTTC GGTTCC  
TATATA ATATAC TATACC ATACCT TACCTG ACCTGG CCTGGT CTGGTA TGGTAA GGTAAT GTAATG TAATGG AATGGA
```

I am trying for loop to read each item in the list and parse it through `mk_model.vector`

the code used is as follows

```
for x in all_seq_sentences[:]:
    mk_model.vector(x)
    print(x)
```

Usually, `mk_model.vector("AGT")` will give an array corresponding to defines dna2vec model, But here rather than actually performing the model run it throws error as

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-77c47b13e98a> in <module>
      1 for x in all_seq_sentences[:]:
----> 2     mk_model.vector(x)
      3     print(x)
      4 

~/Desktop/DNA2vec/dna2vec/dna2vec/multi_k_model.py in vector(self, vocab)
     35 
     36     def vector(self, vocab):
---> 37         return self.data[len(vocab)].model[vocab]
     38 
     39     def unitvec(self, vec):

KeyError: 664
```

Looking forward to some help here

Comment: Hi @Kay - it would help people understand your problem a little better if you were more precise about what you are starting with. You say you're starting with a list but the code you posted is just a bunch of letters — we can't tell if that's one list of strings like `['CTCCTC', 'TCCTCT', 'CCTCTC']` of a list of lists: `[['CTCCTC'], ['TCCTCT', 'CCTCTC']]`. Or one giant string.  Or something else. It would be much clearer if you posted actual python that describes what you have.

Comment: Also, that key error `664` suggests maybe you are passing this whole string in rather than splitting it into individual components.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thanks! but any idea on how can i pass one item at a time from the list.. really appreciate the help! I am treating the DNA sequences as sentences and then broke in down into words. its an implementation of DNA2vec model

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're starting with. Is that one big string? If so you can get a list by calling `split()` on in.

Comment: @MarkMeyer .. thanks, it worked with split()

Answer (score 0):

The above problem was having issues because the for loop took all items in first line as one item, which is why `.split()` was best solution of it. To read follow https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html

working code:

```
for i in all_seq_sentences:
    word = i.split()
    print(word[0])
```

and then later implement another loop to access the model.vector function

```
vec_of_all_seq = []
for sentence in all_seq_sentences:
    sentence = sentence.split()
    for word in sentence:
        vec_of_all_seq.append(mk_model.vector(word))
```

vector representation derived from model.vector will be saved in numpy array named `vec_of_all_seq`.